# Tapping in the UISearchBar causing table contents to shift down, and periodically the searchbar itself will move

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

My search is working perfectly, however when I first tap into the searchbar the cells from the tableview it is attached to will visibly shift down revealing the 'pull to refresh'.  I am using a separate search controller as the search is reused in other views.

```
    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self.resultsController
    self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Type symbol or company ..."
    self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 12, green: 26, blue: 29, alpha: 1.0)
    self.searchController.searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.resultsController.searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar
    tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
```

***Note*** self.resultsController is a custom UITableViewController with appropriate methods and an extension for the results updater.

Can anyone tell me what would cause this sort of behaviour and how I can correct it?

Here are some screens to help illustrate the issue:

[image: Placement is correct on initial load]
[image: Everything shifts once tapping into search]

The interesting thing is that if I navigate to another view, or refresh the initial tableview.  The layout corrects itself, and the search behaves exactly as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried numerous solutions, but noting the behaviour above.  Once you activated search, then navigated to another view.  Any subsequent access of the search it was positioned correctly.

I moved my search code into the viewWillAppear method in my table view controller and vola.  It works perfectly.

I suspect this has to do with the fact that my layout is

TabController -> NavigationController -> TableviewController

Answer (score 0):

Put the following line in `viewDidLoad` solved the problem for me:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = false
```